# How to create a modal using angular components?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angular-components

I'm pretty new to angular, and I'm trying to create a modal as a component (trying not to use ui-bootstrap or libraries) and I'm having trouble wrapping my head around it. My code:

```
App.component('modal', {
  templateUrl: '../modal.html',
  controller: ChocoListCtrl
});
```

I have a `modal.html` which I want to reference my controller which displays items inside a cart:

```
<h2>Your Cart</h2>
<div ng-if="!cart.length">
    There are no items in your cart
</div>
<div class="col-lg" ng-repeat="item in cart | unique : 'type'">
    <div class="col-md">
      <span>Type: </span>
      <strong>{{item.type}}</strong>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md">
      <strong>${{item.price}}</strong>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md">
      <span>Quantity: </span>
      <strong>{{item.quantity}}</strong>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md">
        <button ng-click="removeItem()">Remove</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

However that's really the extent of my knowledge. I'm not sure how to make the modal popup work or even start it. Any guidance would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: One way is to examine the source code of UI Bootstrap. You don't have to use the library, but there is much to learn by reading the source.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you've defined your component well, all you have left to do is rig up the trigger:

```
<modal ng-if="showModal"></modal>
<button ng-click="showModal = !showModal">Show Modal</modal>
```

This may change based on the configuration of the parent element, but it's the same idea.

Then style the modal in such a way that it pops up in the desired location. position:fixed, etc.

You may want to consider dropping a backdrop behind the modal that has an ng-click attached to it to close the modal.